# Upgrade to 16.04 LTS interrupted

Tags: command-line, 16.04, upgrade, resume

During the installation process of upgrading from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS in Terminal I was asked whether an old version of "rcS" should be updated or not. I pressed "D" for showing differences between versions. Now I don't know how to go back to resume installation.

Answer (score 3):

Pressing "q" did the job. Brings me right back to the choices.